# Toggle columns after exporting to excel using ssrs

Tags: reporting-services

I am creating a report with many columns. The main purpose of this report is to be exported to Excel .

My purpose that i would like to find a way to add a toggle item for empty column and reduced them by default. These columns are not deleted in SSRS even in Excel but just hidden.
I tried the following statement using ssrs 2012 but it dosen't work :

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "EXCEL",true,false)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated .

Comment: Do you want to hide the column or toggle it? I know that it can be hidden if the data is null easy enough and should stay hidden if exported.

Comment: @Bactos I would like to toggle it if the data is null

Comment: I don't think there is a way to toggle based on an expression. You can hide the Column based on null by using IsNothing(); but I cant see anyway of setting a toggle through the use of a function. It is either 'Toggle this' or 'Don't toggle this'

Comment: I want to add +/- for empty columns

Comment: I understand what you are saying. Though I don't think it is possible to set an expression to toggle something. If you know what Columns are going to be null before hand you could just put the toggle on the those columns. But actually making it toggle based on it being 'null' does not appear possible (at least not with setting an expression against it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

placing a hidden attribute on the column your column group headers based on "xls=true" would hide any columns not needed for that export. Am I missing anything?